# VK_API ID пользователя определяется как 0

Tags: python, вконтакте

Сделал ВК бота на Python, используя `VkBotEventType`.
Раньше он работал на `VkEventType`, но пришлось переходить на `VkBotEventType`.

На `VkEventType` нормально определялся ID пользователя, а на `VkBotEventType` определяется как 0. Что делать? Все перерыл.

Comment: На VkEventType id был в переменной event.user_id.
На VkBotEventType я думал что в переменной event.object['id'], но в ней-то и возвращался id 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы используете `VkBotEventType` и соответственно `VkBotLongPoll`, то получать Вам нужно не `user_id`, а `chat_id`.
Находится он в объекте `event`.

Используйте:

```py
event.chat_id
```

***UPD:***
Для универсальности, чтобы отвечать и в ЛС сообщества и в беседы, можно использовать `peer_id`, получить его можно так:

```py
event.object['peer_id']
```

Comment: Тоесть как? Это вписывать в поле user_id или куда? 
Тоесть user_id=event.chat_id?

Comment: Ваш бот находится в какой-то беседе, я правильно понимаю? По крайней мере, я сделал такой вывод, потому что Вы используете `VkBotEventType`. В таком случае, Вам вообще не нужен больше `user_id`. Теперь вы работаете с `chat_id`. При отправке сообщения в беседу указывайте его в запросе и забудьте про `user_id`.

Comment: `[100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: you should specify
 peer_id, user_id, domain, chat_id or user_ids param` тоесть, `VkBotEventType ` исключительно для бесед, я правильно понял?

Comment: `VkBotEventType` и `VkBotLongPoll` - это средства для работы с [API для чат-ботов](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs). Скажите, что Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Хочу, чтобы мой бот на `VkBotEventType` работал не только в беседах, в беседах он работает, но в ЛС перестал отвечать.

Comment: Давайте продолжим обсуждение в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95068/izzytopd).

Comment: Написать сообщение в чат не могу, но вариант с peer_id помог, благодарю и прошу прощения за потраченное ваше время